# MPMoviePlayerController and MPMediaPlayback.currentPlaybackRate

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to change the currentPlaybackRate of MPMoviePlayerController to slow down a video.

This is my source code:

```
moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[moviePlayer setCurrentPlaybackRate:5];
moviePlayer.currentPlaybackRate = 5;
```

I really don't understand. Where is my error ?

This is the Apple Documentations:

**MPMoviePlayerController (class):**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/

**MPMediaPlayback (protocol):**
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MPMediaPlayback/currentPlaybackRate

This is the source code of my file.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

@protocol MPMediaPlayback

    // The current playback rate of the now playing item. Default is 1.0 (normal speed).
    // Pausing will set the rate to 0.0. Setting the rate to non-zero implies playing.
    @property(nonatomic) float currentPlaybackRate;

@end

@interface StreamingMedia : CDVPlugin

- (void)playVideo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
- (void)playAudio:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

This is the header source code of my file.m:

```
#import "StreamingMedia.h"
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface StreamingMedia()
    - (void)parseOptions:(NSDictionary *) options type:(NSString *) type;
    - (void)play:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *) command type:(NSString *) type;
    - (void)setBackgroundColor:(NSString *)color;
    - (void)setImage:(NSString*)imagePath withScaleType:(NSString*)imageScaleType;
    - (UIImage*)getImage: (NSString *)imageName;
    - (void)startPlayer:(NSString*)uri;
    - (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification;
    - (void)cleanup;
@end

@implementation StreamingMedia {
    NSString* callbackId;
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
    BOOL shouldAutoClose;
    UIColor *backgroundColor;
    UIImageView *imageView;
}


NSString * const TYPE_VIDEO = @"VIDEO";
NSString * const TYPE_AUDIO = @"AUDIO";
NSString * const DEFAULT_IMAGE_SCALE = @"center";

// SOURCE CODE
```

Where is my error ?